# Why is my animation (rotate) moving around?

Tags: javascript, css

Can anyone tell me why is my div element moving around when I only want it to rotate? As you can see it it is like its rotating around something else. I have tried to fix it with transform-origin and transform-box but it doesnt work...

Here is the code:

```css
#demo3 {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  animation: rotation 15s infinite linear;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}

@keyframes rotation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="demo3">We are Simplifix. We make design simple.</div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/circletype@2.3.0/dist/circletype.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      new CircleType(document.getElementById("demo3"));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you inspect in dev tools, hovering `#demo3` seems to show that the text is overflowing the rotated element. (So, the animation is functioning correctly, the issue is the size of the container vs the content)

Comment: Add background color to the #demo3 element for easier visualization.

Comment: Thank you very much! I removed the width and height and it worked!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.